# JS rest api update html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I'm making a simple JS which consumes a Rest api. Basically the user types in a city, clicks submit and based on that JS generates a GET call. Then using jQuery the script inserts the received data into HTML document. So every time a user clicks submit I want the contents of ny HTML to be filled with new data from te API (without refreshing the page of course). My plan was to structure the script in a way that firstly JS deletes all the prievious content from HTML (run .empty() on each element) and afterwards add new data. Is there an easier way of doing that?

Comment: depends on the HTML structure, really.

Comment: @ADyson What do you mean? I want to display some simple text data ( for ex. local time, temperature etc.). I want to insert those into HTML table or simply into <p> elements. I am just looking for a easy way to clear and replace this data in JS

Comment: I mean whether there's an easier way of clearing it down than running .empty() on every element separately. That's what you were asking, i think? Whether that's possible would depend on the HTML structure, so please give us an example of what that looks like, what your incoming data looks like, and which bits you need to empty out. The devil is always in the detail.

Comment: @ADyson That's exactly that

Comment: If the structure is any more than trivial, or involves a reasonable number of fields, it might make sense for you to use some sort of JS templating engine - there are loads of free ones (you probably only need a super-simple one, not the big frameworks)

Comment: e.g. something like [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) might suit you (see the section "Templates" on that page)